# program received signal SIGABRT (xcode)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface tableview : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource>

{
    NSArray *listOfItems;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *listOfItems;

@end


#import "tableview.h"

@implementation tableview
@synthesize listOfItems;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ]autorelease];
    }

    //NSString *cellValue = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    listOfItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"first",@"second",@"third", nil];

    //listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   // [listOfItems addObject:@"first"];
    //[listOfItems addObject:@"second"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [listOfItems release];
    [super dealloc];
}



@end
```

> 2012-04-27 13:33:23.276 tableview test[438:207] -[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6855500
>   2012-04-27 13:33:23.362 tableview test[438:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>
>   '-[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector
>
>   sent to instance 0x6855500'
>
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (0x13bb052 0x154cd0a 0x13bcced 0x1321f00 0x1321ce2 0x1ecf2b 0x1ef722 0x9f7c7 0x9f2c1 0xa228c 0xa6783 0x51322 0x13bce72 0x1d6592d
>   0x1d6f827 0x1cf5fa7 0x1cf7ea6 0x1d8330c 0x23530 0x138f9ce 0x1326670
>   0x12f24f6 0x12f1db4 0x12f1ccb 0x12a4879 0x12a493e 0x12a9b 0x2282
>   0x21f5)
>       terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c (gdb)

Comment: Table View's datasource and delegate properties are not set properly. You need to add more details what you are using and why it is crashing.

Comment: The problem is here: [UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6855500. Please post the code in which you use this table view..

Comment: m trying to get transfered from a view which contains a button..on pressing that button i want to b tranfered to a new view which contains a tableView..but each time i debug i get this error...i've tried resetting the iOS simulator but it doesn't work

Comment: Please someone help me out...its very URGENT!!

Answer (score 0):

@interface tableview : UIViewController....

Instead of UIViewController try using UIView

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed `UITableViewDelegate`.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is now incompleted. Your "tableView" is not the real UITableView, it's the UIViewController!

You should have the UITableView instance in your h file, and xib file, then link them each other, and set UITableViewDelegate proprty to your UIViewcontroller class.

Please check out the basic UITableView(Or UITableViewController) samples...